# How to insert video in databaes and fetch on page using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, video, file-upload, upload

This is my code for `uploading video` on database or move to folder.
In this code  video uploaded but not insert file into database....??

please help me how to insert video in database using PHP + MySQL ?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
 <body>
  <form ACTION="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label><br>
   <input type="file" name="video"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</body>
</html>

  <?php
    if(isset($_FILES['video']))
     {     
        $name = $_FILES['video']['name'];
        $type = explode('.',$name);
        $type = end($type);
        $size= $_FILES['video']['size'];
        $random_name = rand();
        $tmp= $_FILES['video']['tmp_name'];


       if($type !='mp4' && $type !='MP4' && $type !='flv')
       {
       $message ="Video Format Not Supported";
        }
       else
        {
        move_uploaded_file($tmp, 'videos/'.$random_name.'.'.$type);

       mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'videos' VALUES ('', '$name',   
        'videos/$random_name.$type')");

        $message ="Successfully Uploaded";
        }

         echo "$message <br/> <br/>";
        }
       ?>
```

Comment: Wrong INSERT Statement, table Column(s) are missing

Comment: Just noticed you did not define the table names, thats why it is not saving anything

Comment: i will match match the name but data not insert

Comment: this is my table


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `videos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` blob NOT NULL,
  `url` blob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: hello anybody is here


 
this is my table CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS videos ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name blob NOT NULL, url blob NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied this code from my file, hope this solves your problem.

```
$vdo=$_FILES['uf']['name'];     $target_path = "video/";
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uf']['name']);
$target_path . basename( $_FILES['uf']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uf']['tmp_name'], $target_path))
{  $host="mysqlbhost.com";
$username="me";
$password="me";
$db_name="db";
$tbl_name="video";
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db ("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(video)
VALUES('$vdo')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "<div id='rslt'>"; echo "Thanks! video has been sent to ";
```

Comment: hii
Coding Horror
Thanks